# Changing the http-equiv= tag between pages

Tags: meta

Is it possible to modify the meta tag “http-equiv” in the local.xml? What I’m trying to achieve is rendering a tag on one page that reads: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />` and on another page: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9” />`. Is it possible to do this, or will I have to write PHP logic in the head.phtml file to achieve this?

Comment: Please, how can change the position of this code? I would like to have it above the <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> and now it is under stylesheets and so on. So it doesn't work in IE. And what is the handler name of the first landing checkout page? I tried <checkout_onepage_index>...</checkout_onepage_index> but with this it doesn't work. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard method to do this but you can use the `core/text` block. You can set a different value per layout handle

```
<[page_handle]>
   <reference name="head">
      <block type="core/text" name="ua-compatible">
         <action method="setText">
           <text><![CDATA[<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />]]></text>
         </action>
      </block>
   </reference>
</[page_handle]>
```

If the meta tag is already on the page edit the `head.phtml` to remove it first.